# Nested JSON to Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, json, pandas

I'm trying to expand nested json to pandas dataframe, but the offered solutions haven't worked for me.

My case is:

I have json data in MongoDB.

When I connect with this database, it works well, but the problem is when I need to expand nested json to pandas dataframes, because there are columns where I have json object.

```
index   id    name         location
0       0001  George       [{'country':'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioquia', 'city': 'Medellin'}]
1       0002  Gilberth     [{'country':'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioquia', 'city': 'Medellin'}]
2       0003  Christopher  [{'country':'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioquia', 'city': 'Medellin'}]
```

I need to convert to dataframe something like this:

```
index   id    name         country   department  city
0       0001  George       Colombia  Antioquia   Medellin
1       0002  Gilberth     Colombia  Antioquia   Medellin
2       0003  Christopher  Colombia  Antioquia   Medellin
```

Here I show how to read json data:

```py
json_documents = list(properties.find({}))
df = pd.DataFrame(json_documents)
df.head(2)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
df2=df['location'].apply(lambda x: pd.DataFrame(x)) 
pd.concat([df[df.columns[:-1]],df2],axis=1)
```

---

Also you can try `json_normalize`

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
df=json_normalize(json_documents)
```

Comment: The first solution doesn't work for me.

Comment: 0                     address      city   country d...
1                              address      city   ...
Name: location, dtype: object

Comment: I obtained this.

Comment: The second solution works if exists the column in all json documents, but sometimes a specific column doesn't exist. How can I do in that situation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try.

```py
df["location"].apply(pd.Series)
```

Comment: It doesn't work.

Comment: I obtained this:

0 {'country': 'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioqu...
1 {'country': 'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioqu...
2 {'country': 'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioqu...
3 {'country': 'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioqu...
4 {'country': 'Colombia', 'department': 'Antioqu...